# How to append XML string to existing XML file using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I would like to append a `String` representing an XML element to an existing XML file using JAXB.

For example, I have below XML in a single `String` variable:

```
<servername>aaaaaa</servername>
<ipaddress>121212121</ipaddress>
<port>8080</port>
```

And I want to include this in another `<server>` tag in my XML.
My existing XML file has this contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<servers>
    <server>
        <servername>bbbbbb</servername>
        <ipaddress>11.11.11.11</ipaddress>
        <port>8080</port>
    </server>
</servers>
```

And I would like to add the contents of the `String` variable to this file so that its contents becomes as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<servers>
    <server>
        <servername>bbbbbb</servername>
        <ipaddress>11.11.11.11</ipaddress>
         <port>8080</port>
    </server>
    <server>
         <servername>aaaaaa</servername>
         <ipaddress>121212121</ipaddress>
         <port>8080</port>
    </server>
</servers>
```

How can I achieve this with JAXB?

Comment: Please read [ask] and improve your question accordingly. As is, it will hardly receive an answer.

Comment: Minor improvement of formatting, the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the answer by myself

**Server.java**

```
package com.tools;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "server")
public class Server {

    private String servername;
    private String ipaddress;
    private int port;

    public Server() {
    }

    public Server(String servername, String ipaddress, int port) {
        super();
        this.servername = servername;
        this.ipaddress = ipaddress;
        this.port = port;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getServerName() {
        return servername;
    }

    public void setServerName(String servername) {
        this.servername = servername;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getIpAddress() {
        return ipaddress;
    }

    public void setIpAddress(String ipaddress) {
        this.ipaddress = ipaddress;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return servername + " " + ipaddress + " " + port;
    }
}
```

**Servers.java**

```
package com.tools;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "servers")
public class Servers {

    private List<Server> servers;

    public List<Server> getServers() {
        return servers;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "server")
    public void setServers(List<Server> servers) {
        this.servers = servers;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return servers.toString();
    }

}
```

**Main File**

```
package com.tools;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class ToolConfiguration {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String configFileName = "/config.xml";
        File configFile = new File(ToolConfiguration.class.getResource(configFileName).getFile());
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Servers.class);
            // Read XML
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Servers servers = (Servers) unmarshaller.unmarshal(configFile);

            Server server = new Server("abv", "1.9.3.5", 8080);

            List<Server> serversList = servers.getServers();
            serversList.add(server);

            servers.setServers(serversList);

            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            marshaller.marshal(servers, configFile);

            /*List<Server> serversList = servers.getServers();
            for (Server server : serversList) {
                System.out.println(server.toString());
            }*/

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```